# Zend_Soap_Client switch from WAMP to LAMP and params won't set properly

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-soap

All the required libraries are set for soap. I'm using standard WSDL. Moved my code to the LAMP (RedHat Enterprise).

```
$params = array(
    'test1'=>'Testing',
    'test2'=> '1'
);
$soapClient->method1($params);

$soapClient->getLastRequest();
```

Result:

```
<test1>Testing</test1>
<test2>false</test2>
```

Has this ever happened to anyone and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue may be how Zend_Soap_Client when the WSDL has a parameter that is defined as boolean will not properly convert a "true", "1" into a boolean true. I had to force the data type to be set manually. Once that was done everything worked.

```
$params = array(
    'test1'=> 'Testing',
    'test2'=> true
);
```

I believe the reason this happened had to do the with the different versions of PHP.